# ArrayDeque<>(int capacity) - what's the difference between Scanner.nextInt() == 4 and (int) 4?

Tags: java, collections, arraydeque

The task is to write a program that reads numbers and stores them to a deque.

Sample Input is: 4 1 2 3 4
Sample Output: 4 2 1 3

An even number should be added as the first element, an odd number - as the last. After, the program must output all elements from the first to the last.

Here is my piece of code:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(sc.nextInt());

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            int nextInt = sc.nextInt();
            if (nextInt % 2 == 0) {
                deque.addFirst(nextInt);
            } else deque.addLast(nextInt);
        }

        for (int elt : deque) {
            System.out.println(elt);
        }
    } 
}
```

Sample Output: 4 2 1 3

It works fine, it's correct. BUT!

Let's rewrite

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(sc.nextInt())
```

as

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(4)
```

For this one, sample output is: 4 2 4 1 3 .
i.e. it's incorrect.

Why inputing the same capacity different way gives such different results?

Comment: In the first case, you ask the user for a first integer and use that as the capacity of the deque. And then the 4 next integers are stored in the deque. In the second case, you store all 5 integers in the deque, since you're not using the first one as the capacity of the deque anymore… You should be able to figure that out by yourself. Take the habit of debugging your code, either by executing each line one by one using a debugger, or simply by adding println() statements in the code to understand what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have much to do with how you pass the capacity. It has more to do with how many times `Scanner.nextInt` is called inside the loop.

Because there are always 5 inputs and the first input is always the size, if you do

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(sc.nextInt())
```

`sc.nextInt` will be called 5 times in total (because you have 5 inputs), 4 times inside the loop and 1 time in the line above, and so 4 numbers will be added to the Deque. This is correct.

If you did this however:

```
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(4)
```

`sc.nextInt` will be called 5 times inside the loop, and so 5 numbers will be added to the Deque. But the first number actually shouldn't be added to the Deque, because it is the size, hence producing the wrong output.

`ArrayDeque` is resizable so you don't actually need to specify the size and your code will still work.

You can ignore the first input by calling `sc.nextInt` before the loop:

```
sc.nextInt();
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
   ...
```